# Print a list by C program can not print last number

Tags: c, linux

I write a list by C language. But it can not get the last number. The program accept some number when the number is not `0`. And put number into a list. This is code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct List{
    int data;
    struct List *next;
}List;

void initList(List **pList)
{
    *pList = NULL;
}

List *createList(List *pHead)
{
    List *p1, *p2;
    p1 = p2 = (List *)malloc(sizeof(List));
    if(p1 == NULL || p2 == NULL) {
            exit(0);
    }

    scanf("%d", &p1->data);
    p1->next = NULL;//create a node

    while(p1->data != 0) {
            if (pHead == NULL){
                    pHead = p1;
            }else{
                    p2->next = p1;
            }
            p2 = p1;
            p1 = (List *)malloc(sizeof(List));
            scanf("%d", &p1->data);
            p1->next = NULL;
    }
    return pHead;
}

void printList(List *pHead)
{
    if(pHead == NULL){
            printf("empty");
    }else{
            while(pHead->next != NULL){
                    printf("%d ", pHead->data);
                    pHead = pHead->next;
            }
    }

}

int main()
{
    List *pList = NULL;
    initList(&pList);
    pList = createList(pList);
        printList(pList);
    return 0;
}
```

The program returns `1 2 3` when I input `1 2 3 4 0`. Could someone give me some advice? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`; then learn how to use the `gdb` debugger!

Comment: Note that you should [never cast the result of malloc in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check whether `pHead` is `NULL` instead of `pHead->next`. When you check `pHead->next`, you are exiting at the top of the loop without ever printing the last element.

```
void printList(List *pHead)
{
    if(pHead == NULL){
        printf("empty");
    }else{
        while(pHead != NULL){
            printf("%d ", pHead->data);
            pHead = pHead->next;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
p1 = p2 = (List *)malloc(sizeof(List));
```

`p1` and `p2` are pointing to same location.

This statement allocates memory for the `List` and assigns to `p2` and the same value is assigned to `p1`

Allocate individually for both `p1` and `p2`
    p1 = malloc(sizeof(List));
    p2 = malloc(sizeof(List));

Type cast is not required.